# Vue CSP unsafe-eval

Tags: node.js, vue.js, content-security-policy

I am trying to set proper CSP on my Node server, that serves my Vue app. If I set script-src to self, I get the following error:

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed  source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Of course this could be fixed by adding unsafe-eval, but this is not ideal for security. Does anyone know of a way to get this working without adding unsafe-eval?

I am using Vite so as far as I know my built files will be using the runtime-only version of Vue

Here is my build output:

```
assets
---->
    xy.z12345.svg
    //etc...
    index.HASH.css
    index.HASH.js
favicon.ico
index.html
```

The error is caused by the following code from line 26086 of index.js (minification disabled):

```
function compileToFunction(source, options = {}) {
  {
    const onCacheKey = options.onCacheKey || defaultOnCacheKey;
    const key = onCacheKey(source);
    const cached = compileCache[key];
    if (cached) {
      return cached;
    }
    let occurred = false;
    const onError = options.onError || defaultOnError;
    options.onError = (err) => {
      occurred = true;
      onError(err);
    };
    const { code: code2 } = baseCompile(source, options);
    const msg = new Function(`return ${code2}`)();
    return !occurred ? compileCache[key] = msg : msg;
  }
}
```

Comment: The obvious reason is NOT using runtime only version, but since you're sure it's not the case, it's unknown what it is. Currently can be debugged only on your side.  "but this is not ideal for security" - it's ok as you can guarantee that user data won't end up evaluated as a script, this cannot be so guaranteed all the time but often it can

Comment: I'm finding it tricky to work out if I *am* actually using the runtime-only version. The build script just calls *vite build*, and my filenames in dist do not line up with any in the docs. I have added my build output to the answer if that helps?

Comment: No, this is regular build output. You need to check call stack of the error and track the line where it originates from. You can disable the minification if you have troubles with debugging minified code

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I can switch to the runtime-only version when using Vite to scaffold the project? The error originates from a call to *new Function()*

Comment: Something like that https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4158

Comment: Thanks - it seems that by default it should be using runtime only, and aliasing to vue.esm-bundler.js uses the full build version (according to the docs). The file size has increased for the built code so it would appear this is the case. I am still getting the error but it is expected with the full build, it shouldn't have been happening before however. Very confusing